# Can multiple inheritance always be avoided?

Tags: multiple-inheritance

As you switch from C++ to Java you come across, at some point, the problem of "Java has no multiple inheritance" and then you go online and find 8475349857 articles describing how multiple inheritance can be avoided (while making your code, sometimes, more cumbersome).

I can't help asking myself: is it always avoidable? Is there any scenario where you really need multiple inheritance and can't use composition or some other gimmick to simulate it?

Comment: I think your question needs more definition. What do you mean by "avoidable"? In a trivial sense it is always avoidable: Turing machines have no inheritance, they can be simulated (up to memory limits) in Java (or assembly language, for that matter), and they can compute anything computable (in C++ or any other multiple-inheritance language).